# Deploying AWS .NET SDK project failing

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have configured the .NET SDK in Visual Studio to use IAM credentials (which are being encrypted to the app.configs such as is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-setup.html  I then wrote a call to my S3 server to get a presigned URL so I could display it in my .NET desktop app.  When I run the app from my computer (through VS or by clicking the Executable) the pictures load fine from S3.  When I move the bin folder files (I copy the Release directory to the 5 client computers) it doesn't work on those machines!

I've thought about trying to run an install (which has several draw backs that stem from my lack of experience creating installers).  The only thing I could see this changing, is if the encryption of the IAM key uses a MAC address and the installer re-requests the IAM credentials, then it would work.

The error I get on the other PC's is: "Failed to retrieve credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service."

The machines are on a network whose public IP is white listed to another IAM role with FullS3 Permissions but the Group the Security Key is in also has FullS3 permissions so I wouldn't think that would matter either.

I'm more than happy to answer any other questions people have because I really want to get it going!  Thank you!

Comment: I think the answer falls into this arena here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#creds-assign  But I'm still confused as to where to tell it my configuration is?  I thought it was supposed to be compiled into the config file (hence all the System.Drawing stuff that showed up after installing the AWS SDK)

Answer (score 1):

I found this article about 45 minutes after posting and after reading it about 3 times I finally saw it!

"SDK Store profiles are specific to a particular user on a particular host. They cannot be copied to other hosts or other users. For this reason, SDK Store profiles cannot be used in production applications."

and "Using a Credentials File
You can also store profiles in a credentials file, which can be used by the other AWS SDKs, the AWS CLI, and Tools for Windows PowerShell. To reduce the risk of accidentally exposing credentials, the credentials file should be stored separately from any project files, usually in the user's home folder. Be aware that the profiles in a credentials files are stored in plaintext."

So the answer is I have to provide a plaintext file with the credentials and simply put it somewhere I believe to be "safe" on the clients computer, then specify that location in the app.config file.